# How to webscrape secured pages in R (https links) (using readHTMLTable from XML package)?

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

There are good answers on SO about how to use readHTMLTable from the XML package and I did that with regular http pages, however I am not able to solve my problem with https pages.

I am trying to read table on this website (url string):

```
library(RTidyHTML)
library(XML)
url <- "https://ned.nih.gov/search/ViewDetails.aspx?NIHID=0010121048"
h = htmlParse(url)
tables <- readHTMLTable(url)
```

But I get this error:  File https://ned.nih.gov/search/Vi...does not exist.

I tried to get past the https problem with this (first 2 lines below)(from using google to find solution (like here:http://tonybreyal.wordpress.com/2012/01/13/r-a-quick-scrape-of-top-grossing-films-from-boxofficemojo-com/).

This trick helps to see more of the page, but any attempts to extract the table are not working. Any advice appreciated. I need the table fields like Organization, Organizational Title, Manager.

```
 #attempt to get past the https problem 
 raw <- getURL(url, followlocation = TRUE, cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
 head(raw)
[1] "\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; 
...
 h = htmlParse(raw)
Error in htmlParse(raw) : File ...
tables <- readHTMLTable(raw)
Error in htmlParse(doc) : File ...
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The new package `httr` provides a wrapper around `RCurl` to make it easier to scrape all kinds of pages.

Still, this page gave me a fair amount of trouble.  The following works, but no doubt there are easier ways of doing it.

```
library("httr")
library("XML")

# Define certicificate file
cafile <- system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")

# Read page
page <- GET(
  "https://ned.nih.gov/", 
  path="search/ViewDetails.aspx", 
  query="NIHID=0010121048",
  config(cainfo = cafile)
)

# Use regex to extract the desired table
x <- text_content(page)
tab <- sub('.*(<table class="grid".*?>.*</table>).*', '\\1', x)

# Parse the table
readHTMLTable(tab)
```

The results:

```
$ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_dvPerson
                V1                                      V2
1      Legal Name:                    Dr Francis S Collins
2  Preferred Name:                      Dr Francis Collins
3          E-mail:                 francis.collins@nih.gov
4        Location: BG 1 RM 1261 CENTER DRBETHESDA MD 20814
5       Mail Stop:                                       Â
6           Phone:                            301-496-2433
7             Fax:                                       Â
8              IC:             OD (Office of the Director)
9    Organization:            Office of the Director (HNA)
10 Classification:                                Employee
11            TTY:                                       Â
```

---

Get `httr` here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html

---

**EDIT:** Useful page with FAQ about the `RCurl` package: http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html

Comment: i get the following error with your code `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

Comment: @TylerRinker Thank you. I tried my code in a clean session and it didn't work. Modification posted. This works in a clean session on my machine. (The edit it to include `ssl.verifypeer = FALSE` in the config.)

Comment: Very nice solution and great use of the new httr.  I was very curious how this one would be solved.  Many government files are on https websites so educational researcher thank you :) +1

Comment: Is there a way to get the link information hidden in the HREF link. for example instead of collen baros as manager, I could also know the ID  0010080638


Manager:</td><td><a target="_new" href="viewdetails.aspx?NIHID=0010080638" class="DVLink">Colleen Barros</a></td>

Comment: Can you please edit the post to remove `ssl.verifypeer = FALSE` - it's really bad security practice, and is not necessary. (You also don't need to set the certificate path, httr does that for you)

Comment: @hadley Done.  As you say, not necessary.  Good catch, thank you.

Comment: you may be able to just run `readHTMLTable(x)` without doing any regexp.  `GET` is all you need to bypass the `https` barrier.

Answer (score 4):

Using Andrie's great way to get past the https

a way to get at the data without readHTMLTable is also below.

A table in HTML may have an ID. In this case the table has one nice one and the XPath in getNodeSet function does it nicely.

```
# Define certicificate file
cafile <- system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")
# Read page
page <- GET(
  "https://ned.nih.gov/", 
  path="search/ViewDetails.aspx", 
  query="NIHID=0010121048",
  config(cainfo = cafile, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
)

h = htmlParse(page)
ns <- getNodeSet(h, "//table[@id = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_dvPerson']")
ns
```

I still need to extract the IDs behind the hyperlinks.

for example instead of collen baros as manager, I need to get to the ID 0010080638

Manager:Colleen Barros

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I have to deal with this problem.  Detects if https in url and uses httr if it is.

```
readHTMLTable2=function(url, which=NULL, ...){
 require(httr)
 require(XML)
 if(str_detect(url,"https")){
    page <- GET(url, user_agent("httr-soccer-ranking"))
    doc = htmlParse(text_content(page))
    if(is.null(which)){
      tmp=readHTMLTable(doc, ...)
      }else{
        tableNodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//table")
        tab=tableNodes[[which]]
        tmp=readHTMLTable(tab, ...) 
      }
  }else{
    tmp=readHTMLTable(url, which=which, ...) 
  }
  return(tmp)
}
```