# XML Package for R: Scraping password protected sites

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I would like to automate data downloads into R from password protected sites.  Examples include https sites for personal downloads (bank and credit card statements), as well as professional work (VPNs and subscription sites).  All activity is totally legal (e.g. password protected), and I suspect other users have or will encounter a similar need.

I am a regular user of the XLM package for web-scraping, but my read of the documentation says little about navigating URLs that require a password.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204503/how-to-use-r-to-download-a-zipped-file-from-a-ssl-page-that-requires-cookies

Comment: Thanks Anthony...this is most helpful.  I also found this link to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692066/how-to-webscrape-secured-pages-in-r-https-links-using-readhtmltable-from-xml